# Jira - Avoid getting mail on change/comment on task I'm the ASSIGNEE

Tags: jira

I'm getting mails from jira for all tasks I'm ASSIGNEE to

This is a good,except I want to avoid getting mail every change/comment I make on this task

I couldn't find any settings in my account, Can this be disabled?

I read in [jira](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/configuring-email-notifications-776636790.html) that it should be the case by default

> Jira's default setting is to not notify users of their own changes. This can be changed on a per user basis via their profile preferences.

Comment: I think you should just contact your Jira Administrator on this topic.

Comment: @SvenKrüger Can you give instruction for Jira Administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the Preferences page in JIRA. [Detailed instructions are here.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver073/managing-your-user-profile-861257126.html#Managingyouruserprofile-Managingemailnotifications)

1. Click on your Profile on the top right of the screen.
2. Click the pencil next to `Preferences`.
3. Change the `My Changes` dropdown value to `Do not notify me`.

You should now no longer get emails for actions you've done on a ticket. **The only downside is that you'll now also no longer get notifications when you create a ticket.**

Comment: I found it under Manage your account -> Products -> Jira settings